# How add a textbox in the title bar?

Tags: xamarin.forms

As the sample below:

```
<ShellItem Title="Bottom Tab Sample"
       Style="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
<ShellSection Title="AR" Icon="ia.png">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ARPage}"/>
</ShellSection>
<ShellSection Title="Photo" Icon="photo.png">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:PhotoPage}"/>
</ShellSection>
```

Two Pages.How to add a textbox(searchbox)in the title bar in xamarin shell?

Comment: By I search, I guess that Xamarin form shell will work in Visual studio 2019, I will update my visual studio 2017 to 2019, and I will look way to do this.

Comment: Do you updated?I want to discuss with you

Answer (score 0):

Like in a "regular" Forms app, you can customize the TitleView in the ContentPage itself.

With Shell, you can use the following to show a SearchBar

```
<Contentpage xmlns=...
    ...
    <Shell.TitleView>
        <SearchBar />
    </Shell.TitleView>
</ContentPage>`
```

Comment: This is not working for me... Is this a proven method?

Comment: @LuvForAirplanes yes, I’m using it. What is “not working” for you and what’s your version of Forms?